# Do I need to resize an image to fit the post?

Tags: images

I'm going to post an image in a blog post, first uploading the image to my server, and using its url.

If the image is bigger than the maximum width of my blog-post, will it take longer to download, or will WordPress squish the image for the space it has to fit?

If I need to make the image the right size to fit, what size? My blog is at http://wordfruit.com/blog

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the built-in WordPress media manager to attach/insert images in posts. That way, if you define `$content_width` appropriately, WordPress will auto-resize `large` sized images to fit accordingly.

Otherwise, you'll have to rely on using CSS to set the `max-width` property for images within your content container (e.g. `#content img{ max-width: 500px; height: auto; }`

Outside of these two methods, WordPress *will not* resize your image. If you insert an image in a post, and that image is wider than your content width, the image will overflow your content area.

Comment: Thanks Chip -- I'm using the 'Add an image' button in WordPress, and then picking 'From url' -- so I guess that's the media manager...? And so the image will resize automatically and won't take longer to load onto the page for users?

Comment: If you're inserting images via URL, then you are *not using* the Media Manager to *attach* images to Posts. You're merely inserting an HTML image tag with an external-URL src. Any time you scale images, you're loading the data less efficiently than absolutely possible. Whether the end user experiences is impacted depends on a LOT of factors.

Comment: Thanks again, Chip. If you have a second for another question... if I crop the image down to a particular size, will that sort the issue? Or does the image size viewed depend on things at the user end? -- And if I can crop it to sort the issue, what size would i crop it to? the blog is at wordfruit.com/blog in case that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks, Chip. I can see that your info here covers it; I'm trying to get to know a bit about WordPress, but my brain is a little slow with technical things, so I'm posting up another question that'll help me clarify. Cheers.